# Powershell SQL and get-childitem not working

Tags: sql, powershell, foreach, get-childitem

I have a very strange behaviour in my script. I query a list of AD accounts from a SQL database. then i generate the path to the home folder for each user. this is working fine

```
$rawdata = SQLSelect "SELECT Vorname,Nachname,AdAccount FROM IT.SapMitarbeiter ORDER BY adAccount"#OrgEinheitKurz"
foreach ($data in $rawdata.Tables[0])
{
    $temppath = ($rootfolder + $($data.AdAccount)).ToString()
    write-host "Path: " $temppath
}
```

The output is for e.g. **Path: \\server\share\username**

Now i will receive the folder content of each folder

```
$rawdata = SQLSelect "SELECT Vorname,Nachname,AdAccount FROM IT.SapMitarbeiter ORDER BY adAccount"#OrgEinheitKurz"
foreach ($data in $rawdata.Tables[0])
{
    $temppath = ($rootfolder + $($data.AdAccount)).ToString()
    write-host "Path: " $temppath
    Get-ChildItem -path $temppath
}
```

Now the Output is **Path: \\server\share\**
the username will not be added to the string anymore and I absolutly don't know why

Would be great if some can help me out.

Thanks alot
Gernot

Comment: Can you try `foreach ($data in $rawdata.Tables[0].Rows)` ?

Comment: Try also adding ```write-host "AdAccount: '$($data.AdAccount)'"``` just before the ```write-host "Path: " $temppath``` to make sure your row isn't ```$null``` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. The Problem was the Server I am running the scripts on. On an onther Server it is working fine. 
Very strange..